# Prolog Predicate to get all possible combinations of 4 players in a schdeule

Tags: prolog

That is what I want to have (without facts) and player 1 not meeting player 2 :-

```
?- schedule_round(4,X).
X = [game(1, 3, semi_finals), game(2, 4, semi_finals)] ;
X = [game(1, 4, semi_finals), game(2, 3, semi_finals)] ;
false.
```

Comment: If done without facts, where does `semi_finals` come from? And how do you wish to specify that player 1 not meet with player 2? Or is all that just "hard-coded"?

Comment: @mbratch I need to get all combinations so if there are facts I think won't be useful though if you can reach the result with facts it is ok tell me ,I don't know how to specify player 1 not meet with player 2 I was asking ,Iam asked to make it like that .

Comment: Some facts can be useful to establish things like relationship between number of players and type of round (e.g., `round(semi_finals, 4).`) It all depends on how you want the whole program to work. I also noticed in your example, that player 3 doesn't meet with player 4. Is that also a requirement?

Comment: @mbratch no the requirement is that player 1 and 2 don't meet until it cannot be avoided.